# Does weak attribute only work with shared library in Linux GCC?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, weak-linking

I am a newbie in Linux gcc.  I am writing a simple code to learn the weak attribute in Linux gcc.

See my sample code:

weakref.c, the main file.  I want to the file could work with or without foo method being defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo(void) __attribute__((weak));

int main() {
  if (foo){
    foo();
    printf ("foo is defined\n");
  } else {
    printf("foo is not defined\n");
  }
}
```

so, I run the following command to compile it and run it:

```
gcc weakref.c -o main_static
./main_static
```

and the output is "foo is not defined", which is what I expected.

Then I created a new file libfoo.c, see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void  foo() {
  printf("Print in foo.\n");
}
```

I attempted 3 ways to try to make main file work with the libfoo.c:

1. Compile the libfoo.c and weakref.c and link the object files.
2. Compile the libfoo.c as a static library, and link it with the object file of weakref.c
3. Compile the libfoo.c as a shared library, and link it with the object file of weakref.c

Only the 3rd way works and get the following output:

```
Print in foo.
foo is defined
```

Could you please let me know if the weak ref only works with a shared library, and why?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> let me know if the weak ref only works with a shared library

Not at all.

Both 1. and 3. are expected to produce "foo is defined".

The 2. is *not* expected to pull `libfoo.o` from `libfoo.a`, because unresolved weak reference from `weakref.o` does not count as unresolved symbol for the purpose of pulling an object from an archive library. However, you can *force* `libfoo.o` to be pulled into the link like so: `gcc weakref.o -lfoo -ufoo`, and then you should again get "foo is defined".

Now that I stated what *should* happen, let's see if the practice agrees. Transcript from a Linux/x86_64 system, using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3` and `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20.1-system.20100303`:

```
$ gcc -c weakref.c libfoo.c
$ ar ruv libfoo.a libfoo.o
ar: creating libfoo.a
a - libfoo.o
$ gcc weakref.o && ./a.out
foo is not defined
```

This is your #1:

```
$ gcc weakref.o libfoo.o && ./a.out
Print in foo.
foo is defined
```

As you can see #1 "works" as I expected, and not as you claimed. You must have made some mistake somewhere.

This is your #2:

```
$ gcc weakref.o -L. -lfoo && ./a.out
foo is not defined
```

Your #2 again, but forcing libfoo.o to be pulled into the link:

```
$ gcc weakref.o -L. -lfoo -ufoo && ./a.out
Print in foo.
foo is defined
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got #1 and #2 working. The reason why #1 failed is because I used ld to link the 2 object files instead of the gcc.